# How do I use an SWF in a Flex 4 skin?

Tags: flex4, flash, mxml, skinning, vector-graphics

I'm skinning a Flex app and I want the graphics to be vectors. I have the design material in an Illustrator file. I want to export from there (or through Flash) as some sort of vector format and use it to skin spark components in Flex. However, I'm having trouble placing an SWF. I've tried the following (among others) to no avail:

```
<mx:Image id="icon" source="@Embed('/assets/global/images/icons/location_icon.swf')" />
```

How do work with SWFs (or any other vector format) for skinning?

Comment: I'm going to claim that was done on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe created a format just for this called FXG that you export from illustrator. It is based on SVG. [check this out](http://www.hulstkamp.com/2009/06/20/advanced-fxg-spark-icon-buttons-with-one-generic-skin-in-flex4-gumbo/439) or search google for FXG Spark examples.